# Why was this rudeness flag declined?

Tags: support, comments, declined-flags, comment-flags

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492854/how-to-set-no-spacing-in-uicollectionviewdelegateflowlayout), the OP commented on a comment of mine (the OP's comment is still there, I was offended so I removed mine):

> just like everything else apple provides to their developers this is complete ass cheeks

I'm no Apple defender, and ruthlessly call out Apple bugs when I see them (as anyone knows who knows my writings), but I don't think my attempt to help the OP by pointing to an Apple documentation / video page that solves the problem posed should have to suffer this kind of language. I find this kind of talk unnecessarily vivid and emotive, I find it offensive, and I myself am offended by it.

But I end up being penalized with a "declined" flag when it is the OP of this question who is at fault.

- Rhetorically: What's my motivation to keep the site clean and courteous if it redounds to my detriment?
- Practically: Why was my flag declined?

Answer (score 24):

I have no idea why your flag was declined. That was clearly an error.

The moderator who handled your flag has been primarily moderating on mobile recently, which does tend to increase the odds of misclicks.

And, for me personally, at least, even when not on mobile, I tend to misclick for comment flags because of terrible UX. The text links are “Delete” and “Decline”. Note the similarity between the two labels: single words of similar lengths, both starting with the substring “De”. I have argued before that the “Delete” should at least be rendered in red for a bit of contrast. Color is not an ideal way of creating visual distinctions, since it doesn’t help color-blind users, but it’s better than nothing, and mod tools are only used by a small number of people. I used to have a userscript that changed the “Delete” link’s color to red, and this helped a *lot*: I could tell that it significantly reduced my friction when making a choice because I didn’t hover nearly as long over the options trying to decide.

Anyway, rude comment gone. Crisis averted.

Having a flag “declined” is not a “punishment”, by the way. It’s just a status message informing you of the result.

Comment: Thanks! It is a punishment at least in that the next time I flag I get pushed back. A kind of probationary atmosphere ensues. That is how I learned what had happened.

Comment: I suggest replacing the "delete" button by "NUKE" and "decline" by "NO WAY!". That would be much clearer, even on nokia.

Comment: Moreover my flag is still marked as declined and I am still getting dinged when I try to post a new flag. So yes it’s a punishment.

Comment: The state of a flag cannot be changed retroactively, so there’s nothing I can do about that message. Either way, I don’t see how a notification that one of your recent flags was declined is anything like a punishment.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre but those both start with `N`, so...